# Specific API call is getting stalled in chrome with .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, angular8, asp.net-core-3.1

I am developing a application using .Net core 3.1 and Angular 8. Every thing is fine with the application except one API call. The API call is of type GET and only that API call is getting stalled. I am not able to find the reason for it as I am calling and utilizing it same as other APIs. And other APIs are working perfectly fine. I have searched for the issue and found that Google Chrome doesn't support more than 6 TCP connections at a time.
I have run the command `netstat -a`and got this which I am not able to understand

[image]

[image]
Below is Angular Code :

```
getAllTrainings(){
    this.apiService.get(environment.master_api_url, 'Training/GetAllTrainingDetails')
      .subscribe(result => {
        if (result) {
          this.allTrainings = result;
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.allTrainings)
          console.log(result, 'getAllTraining');
        }
      },error=>{
        console.log(error, 'error while fetching all trainings')
      })
  }
```

Below is .Net Core Code :

```
 [HttpGet("GetAllTrainingDetails")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllTrainings() {
            var trainingDetails = await _trainingService.GetAllAsync();
            return Ok(_mapper.Map<List<AllTrainingsDto>>(trainingDetails));
        }
```

While debugging I found the issue:

```
public async Task<List<TrainingDetail>> GetAllAsync() {
            return await _dbSet
                .Include(x=> x.ParticipantDetail)
                .Include(x=> x.Trainer)
                .Include(x=> x.Program)
                .Include(x => x.ParticipantDetail)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Participant)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
```

Does any one find something wrong with code which can be the reason for this specific API call getting stalled.

Comment: did you try invoking the same action via Postman?

Comment: @kebek I tried with postman. But postman is not able to handle the request. It is getting stuck and it is shutting down.

Comment: How big is the database, you are doing `GetAllxxx` without any filtering?

Comment: Try, for testing, and put a `.Take(1)` in your `GetAllAsync()` request.

Comment: @Frank Nielsen Currently database is new and doesn't have more records..Database has 13 tables with each not more than 100 records

Comment: but try the `.Take(1)` to see if you hit any limitations.

Comment: @FrankNielsen Yes with `.Take(1)` it is not getting stalled. But its weird scenario for such a small database.

Comment: Ok, then it is properly the size of response where you hit a limit in the framework. Maybe  you don't have so many rows, but many columns and therefor a lot of data is being send back. So either it is the amount of data, or the time it takes to produce and send the response.

Comment: No I don't think so that is the case what it seems to be. None of the tables have more than 10 columns and none of them have more than 100 rows. I had came across big tables and bigger databases never faced such issue. It is something different, I need to debug on that.